# What's an evil eye?

Tags: mark

Mark 7:22 thefts, covetousness, wickedness, deceit, lewdness, an evil eye, blasphemy, pride, foolishness.

What is an evil eye?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "evil eye" is a very eastern idiom that includes more than one single idea as shown by the distinction made in the list of Mark 7:22.  It includes the following:

- Envy and covetousness - see Matt 20:15, "your eye is envious"; Prov 28:22, "A man with an evil eye hastens after riches"
- Moral shortsightedness - Prov 28:22, "A man with an evil eye ... does not consider the poverty to come upon him"
- Thinking evil in many situations, Titus 2:15, "Unto the pure all things are pure: but unto them that are defiled and unbelieving is nothing pure; but even their mind and conscience is defiled."

That is, the "evil eye" is a perverted outlook that seeks to turn every opportunity, even by unfair and dishonest means, to the advantage of the person.  It was this depraved mind that Christ came to change:

> Rom 12:2, 9 - Do not be conformed to this world, but be transformed by
> the renewing of your mind ... Love must be sincere. Detest what is
> evil; cling to what is good.

Answer (score 0):

Mark 7:22
New International Version

> adultery, greed, malice, deceit, lewdness, **envy**, slander, arrogance and folly.

envy,
ὀφθαλμὸς (ophthalmos)
Noun - Nominative Masculine Singular
Strong's Greek 3788: The eye; fig: the mind's eye. From optanomai; the **eye**; by implication, vision; **figuratively, envy**.

"Evil eye" is a figure of speech for envy.

Similar usage is found in Proverbs 28:22:

New American Standard Bible

> A man with an **evil eye** hastens after wealth And does not know that want will come upon him.

New King James Version

> A man with an **evil eye** hastens after riches, And does not consider that poverty will come upon him.